# Javascript append HTML combinated with a FORM

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 1 row of a HTML table with all days of the week and the weeknumber.
These inputs are all empty.
You may fill in every input and it will update the query.
It works for x rows because I am using array names and working with 'for each id update the query'.

Now I created a button that appends HTML to its content with javascript.
Dynamically adding inputs.

However, when I submit these inputs and submit the form, the inputs will not be read, so it won't be updated into the database.

I made sure the

```
<tbody id="input_fields_wrap">
</tbody>
```

are inside the `<form></form>`

(In the tbody inputs will be added by the button).

I made sure all inputs are array.

Here are the steps in screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For your extra information: Iam using 1 row precoded in the HTML. If I used 5 for example instead of 1 precoded row, it is working too.
Only the dynamically javascripted added attributes aren't working.

So this is the precoded HTML (its just there)

```
<div class="col-xs-2" >                         
    <td><input type="text" name="wk[]" class="form-control" value="<?php if ($week_sel_get) { echo $week_sel_get; }else{ echo $week_show; } ?>" placeholder="0" maxlength="2" <?php if ($week_sel_get) { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="m[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"  <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'maandag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="d[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'dinsdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="w[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'woensdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="d[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"  <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'donderdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="v[]" value=""  placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"  <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'vrijdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="za[]" value=""   placeholder="00:00 - 00:00" <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'zaterdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?>  /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="zo[]" value=""  placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"  <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'zondag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
</div>
```

And just below is this:

```
 <tbody id="input_fields_wrap">
 </tbody>
```

Then the add fields button:

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="float:right; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:20px;">
    <input type="button"  class="btn btn-success btn-gradient dark btn-block" id="add_field_button" value="Meer velden +">
</div>
```

And the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $("#add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<tr><div class="col-xs-2" ><td><input type="text" name="wk[]" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="0" /></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="m[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="d[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"    /></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="w[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"    /></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="d[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="v[]" value=""  placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="za[]" value=""   placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="zo[]" value=""  placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td></div></tr> '); //add input box
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is what the blue button does (submit form):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_addr'])) {
    $count = count($_POST['wk']); // Hoeveel ids?
    $idusers_r = $_POST['idusers_r'];
    $wk_post = $_POST['wk'];
    $maandag = $_POST['m'];
    $dinsdag= $_POST['d'];
    $woensdag= $_POST['w'];
    $donderdag= $_POST['d'];
    $vrijdag= $_POST['v'];
    $zaterdag= $_POST['za'];
    $zondag = $_POST['zo'];
     for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ // Voor elke id een loop 
        if ($wk_post[$i] !== '') {
             $sql1="INSERT INTO rooster (idusers, week, maandag, dinsdag, woensdag, donderdag, vrijdag, zaterdag, zondag) VALUES ('$idusers_r','$wk_post[$i]','$maandag[$i]','$dinsdag[$i]','$woensdag[$i]','$donderdag[$i]','$vrijdag[$i]','$zaterdag[$i]','$zondag[$i]')"; //Let's update
          $row_Recordset1=mysqli_query($conn, $sql1); // Run query
        }
    } 
 }
```

This is the whole form:

```
<form action="" method="post"  >
    <input type="hidden" name="idusers_r" value="<? echo $iduser; ?>">
    <?php 
    $week_show = $week;
    if ($_GET['day_sel'] || $_GET['week_sel']) {
        $day_sel_get = $_GET['day_sel'];
        $week_sel_get = $_GET['week_sel'];
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <div class="col-xs-2" >
            <td><input type="text" name="wk[]" class="form-control" value="<?php if ($week_sel_get) { echo $week_sel_get; }else{ echo $week_show; } ?>" placeholder="0" maxlength="2" <?php if ($week_sel_get) { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="m[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"  <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'maandag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="d[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'dinsdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="w[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'woensdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="d[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"  <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'donderdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="v[]" value=""  placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"  <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'vrijdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="za[]" value=""   placeholder="00:00 - 00:00" <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'zaterdag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?>  /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="zo[]" value=""  placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"  <?php if ($day_sel_get == 'zondag') { echo 'style="background:#efefef"'; }   ?> /></td>
        </div>
    </tr> 
    <tbody>
    <tbody id="input_fields_wrap">
    </tbody>
    </table> 
    <div class="col-md-2" style="float:right; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:20px;">
        <input type="button"  class="btn btn-success btn-gradient dark btn-block" id="add_field_button" value="Meer velden +">
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-2" style="float:left; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:20px;">
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-gradient dark btn-block" name="submit_addr"  value="Voeg toe">
    </div>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for reading

Comment: When you look in the developer tools (F12 in browser)  at the network tab, do you see that your dynamically added rows are sent to the server?

Comment: Your html seems to be seriously malformed. Fixing that might just magically fix your issue.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of fields, why not just put them all in the base form, while you .hide the ones you don't want by default (with blank values) and once clicking the button - .show them? Another option is to submit the form on click with javascript while reading all the input texts of a class=form-control, thus you can append any number of input texts to the form

Comment: @Niranjan I have rolled back your edit, because that was completely unreadable

Comment: @xxxmatko nope it didnt. Only the first row.

Comment: @PalDev I am using your options right now. Hide the divisions on load of the page. Show them once they clicked the green button. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to PalDev a simple solution.
Never thought about it.

This is my new javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var add_button      = $("#add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var remove_button      = $("#remove_field_button"); //Add button ID
     $("#remove_field_button").hide();
     $("#input_fields_wrap").hide();

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
       $("#input_fields_wrap").show();
       $("#add_field_button").hide();
         $("#remove_field_button").show();
    });

    $(remove_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
       $("#input_fields_wrap").hide();
       $("#remove_field_button").hide();
         $("#add_field_button").show();
    });


});
```

I created a simple while for showing 3 more inputs by default. And hiding them once the page is loaded

```
<tbody id="input_fields_wrap">
                                            <?php
                                            $max_items = 0;
                                            while ($max_items < 3) {
                                                $max_items = $max_items +1;

                                            ?>
                                            <tr>
                                      <div class="col-xs-2" >


                                        <td><input type="text" name="wk[]" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="0" maxlength="2"  /></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="m[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="d[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="w[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="d[]" value="" placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="v[]" value=""  placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="za[]" value=""   placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"   /></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="zo[]" value=""  placeholder="00:00 - 00:00"  /></td>


                                      </div>
                                      </tr> 
                                      <? } ?>
                                        </tbody>
```

Now the buttons just hide and shows the content.

Thanks for helping